# Driver [meilisearch] not supported

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout, meilisearch

I am trying to set up Meilisearch with laravel/Scout in my laravel project.

```
"laravel/framework": "^7.0",
"laravel/scout": "^8.1",
"meilisearch/meilisearch-php": "^0.18.2",
```

According to the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scout) this package is supported but I got this error:

```
"message": "Driver [meilisearch] not supported.",
    "exception": "InvalidArgumentException",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\marcopolo2.0\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Manager.php",
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MeiliSearch support is in laravel/scout 9, not 8